# Authorization header is not sent in request using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

In my code, I have a request header "Authorization", but in `/docs`, the header is not sent:

```
 @router.get('/versions',tags=["Credentials"],responses={
        200: {
            "model": List[models.versions_info],
            "description": "Return has code",
            "headers": {"Authorization": {"description":"Token party","type":"string"}}
        }})
async def list_versions(request: Request,token: Union[str, None] = Header(alias="Authorization",default=None)): 
    print(token)
    out=[{"version": "2.1.1","url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.1.1/"},{"version": "2.2","url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.2/"}]
    return Response(status_code=200,content=json.dumps(out), media_type="application/json", headers={"Authorization": "Token "+config.globals['mytoken']})
```

In Docs:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pavel, I see You solved the issue already, together with team we created ocpi implementation in python and fastapi, maybe will be useful for You https://github.com/TECHS-Technological-Solutions/ocpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it that way. Authorization is a reserved header here and you can not override it. if you rename it to something different you'll see it in curl and it would work as expected. See here how you can implement jwt-based auth: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/

Or you can use `Security` functionality to archive it. This is a self-contained working example (creds to @Pavel Gribov):

```
from fastapi import Security, Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security.api_key import APIKeyHeader

from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

token_key = APIKeyHeader(name="Authorization")


class Token(BaseModel):
    token: str


def get_current_token(auth_key: str = Security(token_key)):
    return auth_key


@app.get("/get_items")
def read_items(current_token: Token = Depends(get_current_token)):
    return current_token
```

See how it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUNCd.jpg).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to replace the header name, since this is exactly what is described in the specification for the OCPI protocol: https://www.eco-movement.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/OCPI_2.1.1-RC1.pdf (3.1.3 Request format)

Comment: Do not use Header for this, retrieve from request

Comment: But then it won't get into docs?

Comment: It will be added automatically after authentication see screenshots here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#check-it

Comment: if I use OAuth 2, then the "client" will have to support it, but this is not possible, since there is an OCPI specification

Comment: You can do it using Security, see the example (sorry for quality)